# Analysis of following writing pattern

Tags: writing-style, figures-of-speech, dialogue

Is there a name for following writing/dialogue pattern?

> We ride into the future. A future where ...
>
> In the world you grew up. A new world with  ...
>
> It's just a theory. A game theory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These make use of **rhetorical devices**, making sentences shorter and using repetition for emphasis.

Of the rhetorical schemes detailed by [Dr. L. Kip Wheeler](https://web.cn.edu/kwheeler/schemes.html), associate professor of Carson-Newman University, see the following:

> **Anapodoton** -- deliberately creating a sentence fragment by the omission of a clause: "If only you came with me!" If only students knew what anapodoton was! Good writers never use sentence fragments? Ah, but they can. And they do. When appropriate.

And:

> **Anadiplosis** -- repeating the last word of a clause at the beginning of the next clause. As Nietzsche said, "Talent is an adornment; an adornment is also a concealment." Extended anadiplosis is called **Gradatio**. For instance, in *The Caine Mutiny* the captain declares: "Aboard my ship, excellent performance is standard. Standard performance is sub-standard. Sub-standard performance is not allowed." Biblically speaking, St. Paul claims, "We glory in tribulations also, knowing that tribulation worketh patience; and patience, experience; and experience, hope, and hope maketh man not ashamed." On a more mundane level, the character of Yoda states in *Star Wars, Episode I*: "Fear leads to anger; anger leads to hatred; hatred leads to conflict; conflict leads to *suffering*." Gradatio creates a rhythmical pattern to carry the reader along the text, even as it establishes a connection between words.

Comment: @AmanVerma Happy to help! If it's useful, please tick the little green arrow on the left to "accept" this answer :)